# twitter4J TwitterStream not getting imported

Tags: java, spring, twitter4j

I'm trying to use the following stream example for twitter4J:

```
package twitter4j.examples.stream;

import twitter4j.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * <p>This is a code example of Twitter4J Streaming API - filter method support.<br>
 * Usage: java twitter4j.examples.stream.PrintFilterStream [follow(comma separated numerical user ids)] [track(comma separated filter terms)]<br>
 * </p>
 *
 * @author Yusuke Yamamoto - yusuke at mac.com
 */
public final class PrintFilterStream {
    /**
     * Main entry of this application.
     *
     * @param args follow(comma separated user ids) track(comma separated filter terms)
     * @throws TwitterException when Twitter service or network is unavailable
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java twitter4j.examples.PrintFilterStream [follow(comma separated numerical user ids)] [track(comma separated filter terms)]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance().addListener(new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        ArrayList<Long> follow = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<String> track = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String arg : args) {
            if (isNumericalArgument(arg)) {
                for (String id : arg.split(",")) {
                    follow.add(Long.parseLong(id));
                }
            } else {
                track.addAll(Arrays.asList(arg.split(",")));
            }
        }
        long[] followArray = new long[follow.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < follow.size(); i++) {
            followArray[i] = follow.get(i);
        }
        String[] trackArray = track.toArray(new String[track.size()]);

        // filter() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.
        twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(0, followArray, trackArray));
    }

    private static boolean isNumericalArgument(String argument) {
        String args[] = argument.split(",");
        boolean isNumericalArgument = true;
        for (String arg : args) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                isNumericalArgument = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isNumericalArgument;
    }
}
```

at this part 
`TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance().addListener(new StatusListener() {`

But my IDE never offers me any imports for [TwitterStream](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html) nor [TwitterStreamFactory](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStreamFactory.html) I understand that both should be in the general package of twitter4j which I have imported with gradle into this spring application.

Also the IDE keeps offering me to import : `org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusListener` or `ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusListener`

But never [StatusListener](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusListener.html)

How can I overcome this?

Comment: That means you dont have the library imported

Comment: Did you add this - `compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.2'` and apply gradle changes?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I can import all the other packages that I need

Comment: only difference is I have '4.0.1' instead of '4.0.2' , but TwitterStream is supported since '2.0'

Comment: try to sync gradle again

Comment: That did not work either , after gradle sync I've also synchronized IntelliJ just to be sure.

Comment: Can you see the library in the external libraries section of intellij?(Appears in the project structure)

Comment: I can see the library that I've imported, but when i drill down, I don't see that particular class, Although there are no indications , I think I have to research if this has been deprecated . thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.7 and I have the same issue. Other Twitter classes import except the Stream ones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find it mentioned in the documentation, but it seems that you need to import the `twitter4j-stream` artifact rather than the `twitter4j-core` one.

Replacing with this in my POM did the trick:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

The latter is included by the former, but I see in their [examples](https://github.com/Twitter4J/Twitter4J/blob/8376fade8d557896bb9319fb46e39a55b134b166/twitter4j-examples/pom.xml#L110) project that they include both anyways.

You can see all available artifacts in [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.twitter4j).

Comment: For android studio and gradle repository implement following line in build.gradle(app) file:

implementation 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:4.0.7'
with
implementation 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.7'
 
So you can get StatusListener and TwitterStream classes.